# Is the matricial representation of the inverse relation the transpose of the representation of the original relation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, inverse, transpose

here we are studying relations on AxA with A a finite set.
We represent the relation on a matrix in this way:

$M\left ( R \right )_{ij}=1 \; if (i,j) \in R; and M\left ( R \right )_{ij}=0 \;\;otherwise $

It seems that the representation of the inverse relation
$$ R^{-1} = \{\langle x,y\rangle\, |\,\langle y,x\rangle \in R\ \} $$ 
should be the transpose of the matrix of the original relation.

As we could not find it in any book or link, we post the question ( sorry about a bad english )

Comment: Too trivial to look for a book.

Comment: When studying from a text book full of trivialities  you get used to having a third party approval on everything.  Bad habit, I agree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right: the matrix of the inverse relation $R^{-1}$ is indeed $R^T$.

Comment: It was pretty obvious but we could not check it with any of our text books.   Thank you a lot !!! Gracias